# Matlab, configure output of TF (Transfer Functions)

Tags: matlab, output, transfer-function

When using the `tf` function in matlab, I'm not getting exactly the output I need.

For example:

```
tf( 1 , [1 1 1])
```

Produces:

```
ans =

       1
 -----------
  s^2 + s + 1
```

Continuous-time transfer function.

What I desire is this:

```
 ans = 
    1/(s^2 + s + 1).
```

I do not want the pretty format.  I want to access the transfer function directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = tf( 1 , [1 1 1])
```

will return a TF object in f.

Comment: No, you dont understand. Doing what you said does me no good. Even with f = tf(1 , [1 1 1]), all I get is
      f =
          1
     -----------
      s^2 + s + 1

I need f = 1/(s^2 + s + 1)

Comment: @user2033840 do you want access to the actual transfer function or do you want it just displayed as 1/(s^2+s+1) ?

Comment: Just displayed as. I want a function or script that, when applied to said variable f = tf(1 , [1 1 1]), gives me the output 1/(s^2 + s + 1).
Is there such a thing? Or anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Modify `printsys.m` file in control toolbox. Remove `disp(['   ','-'*ones(1,len)])` line to remove the line and print nominator and dominator using single `disp` command.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and could not find a satisfactory solution, so I wrote my own.

It's very simple feel free to use it anyway you wish.

The following function should be placed in tf2string.m

```
% name: tf2string.m
% author: vittorio alfieri

% example:
% W1_out=tf2string(W1)
% 
% W1_out =
% (s + 37.0)/(1.646*s)

function output_string = tf2string(input_tf)

syms s

sym_num=poly2sym(input_tf.num{:},s);
sym_num=vpa(sym_num, 4);
char_num=char(sym_num);

sym_den=poly2sym(input_tf.den{:},s);
sym_den=vpa(sym_den, 4);
char_den=char(sym_den);

output_string = ['(', char_num, ')/(', char_den, ')'];
s=tf('s');
```

-Vittorio